# StaleDataError: DELETE statement on table 'event_services' expected to delete 2 row(s); Only 3 were matched

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a model named `Event`, and a model named `ServicePartner`, they have many-to-many relationship with each other with a secondary join and secondary table named `EventServices`. Now, in the `event_services` table, I have three rows related to a specific `event`. But two of them are related to the `service_partner.id=3` and one of them is related to the `service_partner.id=4`. Now, when I call `event.services` it returns two objects namely `service_partner.id=3` and `service_partner.id=4`. But my desire is removing those relations with `.clear()` I mean I want to remove those three rows in the `event_services` table (secondary table) using `event.services.clear()` and/or `event.event_services.clear()`. But after `session.commit()` I get the following error:

```
StaleDataError: DELETE statement on table 'event_services' expected to delete 2 row(s); Only 3 were matched.
```

Here are my models:

```py
class Event(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "event"

    name = Column(String(1000))
    services: Mapped[list] = relationship(
        "ServicePartner",
        secondary="event_services",
        secondaryjoin="and_(ServicePartner.id==EventServices.service_partner_id, EventServices.deleted==None)",
        back_populates="events",
    )
    event_services: Mapped[list] = relationship("EventServices", viewonly=True)


class ServicePartner(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "service_partner"

    name = Column(String(1000))
    events = relationship(
        "Event",
        secondary="event_services",
        secondaryjoin="and_(Event.id==EventServices.event_id, EventServices.deleted==None)",
        back_populates="services",
    )


class EventServices(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'event_services'

    event_id: Mapped[int] = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("event.id"))
    service_partner_id: Mapped[int] = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("service_partner.id"))
    price: Mapped[int] = Column(Integer, default=0, server_default="0")
    service_name: Mapped[str] = Column(String(255))
    service_partner = relationship("ServicePartner", viewonly=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out I could simply delete those rows using the following procedure instead of `event.services.clear()` and/or `event.event_services.clear()`:

```py
for event_service in event.event_services:
    db.session.delete(event_service)

db.session.commit()
```